# How to generate a mnemonic phrase?

Tags: ethers.js, mnemonic

How to generate not a wallet, but a mnemonic phrase itself? In JS, Python. Not in a wallet application.  No information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ethers.js you can do this:

```
import { Wallet, utils } from 'ethers';

const wallet = Wallet.fromMnemonic(
  utils.entropyToMnemonic(utils.randomBytes(32))
)

console.log('wallet.address:', wallet.address)
console.log('wallet.mnemonic.phrase:', wallet.mnemonic.phrase)
console.log('wallet.privateKey:', wallet.privateKey)
```

Source: [Github](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/324)